# How to create a particular SSRS Expression for this example?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

if some could help me to i will be very grateful.

This can be done by separating the table into 2 tables but I want to do it with a formula if possible.

We have the following report:

[image: REPORT]

We need to get the data from the table and add them into the totals on line 2 (those are textbox, not a table)

"TOTAL ID" and "TOTAL AMOUNT" is easy to do using the expressions:

=CountDistinct(Fields!id.Value, "opp_win_lose") (opp_win_lose = dataset) (we have 3 datasets so we need to put to which dataset it belongs)

=ReportItems!Textbox44.Value

The problem gets at "TOTAL ID STATUS PENDING" and "TOTAL AMOUNT STATUS PENDING"

I need to create the expression with the condition that status = Pending (or Running) that is a group, so we have

TOTAL ID STATUS PENDING = 3

TOTAL AMOUNT STATUS PENDING = 100

Thanks.

Nothing worked, try a few expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to add a condition to the COUNT and SUM fields for the Pending ones.

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!STATUS.Value = "Pending", Fields!id.Value, NOTHING), "opp_win_lose")

=SUM(IIF(Fields!STATUS.Value = "Pending", Fields!AMOUNT.Value, 0), "opp_win_lose")
```

It looks like the summary data is from the same table. It might have been easier to use a table for your summary. Group the table on 1 (the number) so there's only one total line. Then you don't need the name the dataset.

Comment: @dax You should mark this answer as accepted. This helps other find answers to similar questions and gives both yourself and the person who took the time to answer reputation.